# Why doesn't click make that element the active element?

Tags: jquery

I have some boxes in this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/SzDZn/1/ - and I'm wondering why clicking on any of them still shows the body as the active element:

```
$('#blue_box').click(function() {
    alert ("active box is " + document.activeElement);
});
```

The goal here is to actually make a box go away when the click is outside of it, i.e., on its blur event, but I'm not able to even get the boxes to take focus, never mind losing focus.

Thanks

Comment: Because input elements get focus? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.activeElement?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.activeElement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an element to receive focus, it must be able to receive input. None of your "boxes" can so they are not considered to have focus when clicked. There are some ways to bypass the focus requirements by setting a tabindex on elements, but this is still considered to be non standard.

"When there is no selection, the active element is the page's `<body>`. "-[Mozilla - activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.activeElement?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.activeElement)

---

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/SzDZn/2/)***

That answer is to your title, but does not fully address your localized example. In your example, if you wish to have an element become "active" when you click, then just give it a class. For example, lets give each element clicked the class "activeElement". Now, when any click event is registered, we know that if we remove the element with class "activeElement" we will have removed the last box which was clicked. Lets also make sure we don't accidentally allow these click events to propagate or we will remove the wrong elements.

```
$('#red_box').click(function(e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
 $('.activeBox').remove();
 $(this).addClass("activeBox");
 alert($(".activeBox")[0].id + " is the active box");
});

$('#green_box').click(function(e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
 $('.activeBox').remove();
 $(this).addClass("activeBox");
 alert($(".activeBox")[0].id + " is the active box");
});

$('#beige_box').click(function(e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
 $('.activeBox').remove();
 $(this).addClass("activeBox");
 alert($(".activeBox")[0].id + " is the active box");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Travis for your informative and interesting example.  The people here who give questions they think are stupid a negative rating and no answer or a flippant answer don't help the forum.